# How to read .vcf file from browser?

Tags: php, web-crawler, vcf-vcard

I am trying to retrieve all the email addresses from the exhibitors of the [IFA Berlin](http://www.virtualmarket.ifa-berlin.de/en/search?itemtype=person&page=1).
This is pretty easy to crawl though.

But as a tricky part, they just allow us to download a .vcf file or to send an email (throught their server I guess). I would like to find that email address without downloading that vcf file. Otherwise I could download it and read it easily using PHP (since my crawler is also in PHP).

This is also my first question here after lurking for years! Nice meeting you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to read `.vcf` file from browser?

This file will always be a file download and never displayed in a browser. One way to make it work is to setup a custom browser extension, which temporary stores the file and parses the microformat and displays the information.

> PHP scraping approach

There are vcard parsers out there: https://github.com/nuovo/vCard-parser
but i think you could base this on a RegExp solution: `/EMAIL;INTERNET:(.*)/`.

Let's pretend, your first scraping run gives you a list of attendee IDs,
then your second (vcard) scraping run could fetch and extract the name and emails by ID:

```
<?php

function getVcard($id) {
    return file_get_contents('http://www.virtualmarket.ifa-berlin.de/?Action=attendeeVcard&id=' . $id);
}

function getEmailFromVcard($vcard)
{
    preg_match('/EMAIL;INTERNET:(.*)/', $vcard, $matches);
    if(isset($matches[1])) {
        return $matches[1];
    }
}

function getNameFromVcard($vcard)
{
    preg_match('/N:(.*);;/', $vcard, $matches);
    if(isset($matches[1])) {
        $array = explode(';', $matches[1]);
        $name = trim($array[1]) . ' ' . trim($array[0]);
        return $name;
    }
}

$id = 1775586;

$vcard = getVcard($id);
$email = getEmailFromVcard($vcard);
$name = getNameFromVcard($vcard);

echo $name . ' ' . $email;
```

Comment: Wow thank you! Yeah the file is pretty easy to parse, That's what I was about to do, thanks a lot! If I have more questions I'll post them here.

Comment: It's been done in a few minutes thanks to you! I've never used the regexp before, it always looked complicated to me. Do you have any good tutorial about it?
Thanks again

Comment: Regular expression might be a bit confusing at the start, but once you are used to some basic reusable matching expressions the fun-factor kicks in. A good interactive tutorial is http://regexone.com/ . A valuable interactive tool for playing around with and puzzling expressions together is: https://regex101.com/ . You will also get the detailed explanation of whats going on. Example: https://regex101.com/r/qG4vK7/1/ -- The expression i used is `(.*)` - capture anything. The most basic thing.

Comment: Sweet! Thanks, looks really funny